# Getting latitude and longitude from N900 GPS enabled mobile phone using php

Tags: php, gps

I am using N900 mobile(Maemo OS) with GPS enabled. I want to extract its current latitude and longitude values using PHP to be stored in database avaialble in WAMP server.I am very new to this . Plz provide some useful link.Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you're running PHP on your phone and want PHP to extract that information from your mobile device then I"m afraid PHP has no native way of obtaining that information on its own. You would need to figure out how your phone provides that information through its native APIs and interface with it from PHP.

If you're saying you're using your mobile device's browser to visit a remote PHP script then the browser needs to have HTML5 GeoIP support, in which case it still has nothing to do with PHP. The GPS information would be sent by your HTML5-enabled browser to your remote server. You'll need to check out some tutorials online about how to use that functionality.

Here's one example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/

Comment: I checked d link u gave.It works well in my laptop browser...But d prblm s I am not getting d pop up vich asks for sharing my location in my N900 phn...I think my phn's browser doesn't support HTML5...vat sud I do nxt...